# How can I use Perl to extract a particular part of an HTML file

Tags: html, perl

I am new to Perl, I am trying to read specific content between `<div class="one">` of a HTML file.

HTML file:

```
<div class="one">

    <div id="two">Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
    </div>

    <pre>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
    </pre>

</div>
```

Perl Code:

```
my $file = "content.html";

if (-e $file) {
    open(IN, $file);
    while (<IN>) {
        chomp($line = $_);

        #print "$line\n";
    }
}

@contents = <IN>;

#check to if content in html file is in the right location,
#if content is in correct location (div class="one")
#print content in div two and three if exist

for (my $i = 0 ; $i <= $#contents ; $i++) {
    if (!$contents[$i] =~ m/^\s*<div/ && $contents[$i] =~ m/class\s*=\s*"one"/) {
        print "content in wrong location";
    }
    else {
        if ($contents[$i] =~ m/^\s*<div/) {
            print "$_";
        }
        else ($contents[$i] =~ m/^\s*<pre/) {
            print "$_";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a "txt" file, it's an HTML file, and should be handled with an HTML parser.  Down the "parse HTML with regex" road lies madness.

Comment: +1 on using a parser: http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/Parser.pm

Comment: @DavidO: It is a text file that happens to contain HTML. It has a MIME type of `text/html`.

Answer (score 1):

I had some success using [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/~cjm/HTML-Tree-5.03/lib/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm) which is good at handling broken HTML.